# Setting Range, mouse over in nvd3 bullet chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

There are two things I want to achieve in nvd3 bullet chart.

1. I want the starting point to change the starting point from 0. As can be seen in the example, all my relevant data is in the higher side and it gets too crowded at the right end of bullet chart if I start from 0. View would be much better if starting point is around 2000.
2. I want to display something on mouse over on the markers. Is this possible?

This is my code:

```
var data = {
  "title": "Price in Locality",
  "subtitle": "US$, in thousands",
  "ranges": [2500,2700,2900, 3000],
  "measures": [2850],
  "markers": [2800]
};

nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.bulletChart();


d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .call(chart);

return chart;
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/azitabh/uCsvQ/1/).

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question

```
2. I want to display something on mouse over on the markers. Is this possible?
```

Yes, its possible, make sure you pull the latest version on NVD3 from [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3), it has tooltip enabled. Shows the ranges,measures and markers on hover.

Not quite clear on the question 1 sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly a year late on this, but I figured I'd throw this up anyway.

Based on the source of the [bullet chart](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/bulletChart.js), there doesn't seem to be a way to change the starting position from 0 to something higher, as in your first question. (In fact, there seems to be little you *can* change, except the ranges and the color.)

However, it looks like your ranges are in the 2000s. So you could divide all your numbers by 100 and make your `subtitle` property millions instead of thousands and [format your number as a `Fixed`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting).